# How to manipulate values from dropdown and pass it when clicked as a parameter to api in other function with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

How can I display only one type of value `${clickedNames.name_BG}`, but on click get the second type of value `${clickedNames.name}`

```
// Create a function that will insert the data into our legends UL in dropdown
    function listDataNames(dataStation) {
      // Loop through each result and append the data.
      dataStation.floodguard_stations.rows.map(function (clickedNames) {
        const fillNames = `
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${clickedNames.name_BG} - ${clickedNames.name}</a></li>`;
        const item = document.createElement('li');
        item.innerHTML = fillNames;
        list.appendChild(item);
      });
      // Finally append all the data to the UL.
      ulNames.appendChild(list);
    }
```

In this function I get the data from API then I import two items in the drop down menu.

On click I want to pass the clicked value to this function on `apiUrl`:

```
    async function getMikeFWData() {
    const apiUrl = "http://I want to pass the clicked value from dropdown here"

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
    const mikefwdata = await response.json()

    const mikefwdate = mikefwdata.floodguard_mikefw.rows.map((x) => x.date)
    console.log(mikefwdate)
    const mikefwvalue = mikefwdata.floodguard_mikefw.rows.map((x) => x.level)
    console.log(mikefwvalue)

    mikeFWLabelChart = mikefwdate;
    mikeFWDataChart = mikefwvalue;
}
```

I am adding this picture for reference:

I want the values from 1 to be only visible on the dropdown (`${clickedNames.name_BG}`), but the values from 2 (`${clickedNames.name}`)to be submitted as a parameter when clicked.

[This is the demo project](http://194.141.118.43:8080/floodguard/)

[image]

Comment: The OP could provide the value of `clickedNames.name` as [global `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to each list-item's link-element which then on `click` can be read via the link-element's related [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mdn Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-name"));
  });
}
```

```css
li {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li data-name="item 1">item 1</li>
      <li data-name="item 2">item 2</li>
      <li data-name="item 3">item 3</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
     
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can store data which needs to pass in API in data-attribute

For example:

```
const fillNames = `
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-name="${clickedNames.name}">${clickedNames.name_BG} - ${clickedNames.name}</a></li>`;
```

so that it can be fetched when `li` is clicked

```
element.getAttribute("data-name")
```

Comment: When I set data-name="${clickedNames.name}" and after I set dataAPI.nameStation = element.getAttribute("data-name");
    console.log(dataAPI.nameStation);

I receive error: ReferenceError: element is not defined

Comment: @BenJohnson Edited the previous answer with an example on how data-attribute can be used in this scenario